Irreducibility of a Polynomial with Prime Exponents
Let $f(x) = (x^p - a_1)(x^p - a_2) \ldots (x^p - a_{2n}) - 1$
where $a_i \geq 1$ are distinct positive integers where at least two of them are even, and $n \geq 1$ is a positive integer and $p$ is prime. This is a problem I came up with and I’m trying to   see if It’s possible to prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$ (not sure if it’s possible). Maybe I have to change some stuff in the problem's statement for it to be true. Any help is appreciated.

The amount of values in the sequence $(a1, a2, ...)$ need to be even and at least two of them have to be even. Your examples use $n=1/2$, while I am asking about when $n$ is a positive integer (since the final value is $a_{2n}$).

Yes, I thought I had deleted my comment, I was surprised when it showed up. I have deleted it now.

Since $f(x)$ is of the form $g(x^p)$ with $g(x)$ irreducible, $f(x)$ is irreducible if $f(0)$ is not a perfect $p$th power. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626024/elementary-proof-of-irreducibility-criterion/4834069 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962259/if-a-1-a-2-ldots-a-n-are-distinct-integers-then-prove-that-x-a-1x-a-2?rq=1

(Though this does not answer the question one way or the other if $f(0)$ is a perfect $p$th power.)

The $f(x)$ is not irreducible in general. For example:
$$
(x^3-4)(x^3-86)-1=(x^2-6x+7)(x^4+6x^3+29x^2+42x+49)
$$
As noted by @BenjaminWright in the comments, the claim is true if $f(0)$ is not a perfect $p$-th power. Since $f(0)=a_1a_2\cdots a_{2n}-1$ and two of $a_i$'s are even, we have $f(0)\equiv -1\pmod 4$, so it cannot be a perfect square, therefore fully proving the claim for $p=2$.
In remaining cases, we search for a counterexample: we are looking for $a_1a_2\cdots a_{2n}=1+a^p$. By the same reasoning $\bmod 4$ as above, we see that $a \equiv 3\pmod 4$ and $p$ is odd. Also, to simplify the search, we check just $n=1$ and $p=3$ (if we don't find an example there, we can extend the search). Hence, we are iterating over $a=3,7,11,\dots$ and looking at divisors $a_1a_2=1+a^3$. We also need to make sure both $a_1$ and $a_2$ are even (by the "at least two of them are even" condition). This way, we find counterexamples for $p=3$ quickly.
I am searching for counterexamples with $p>3$ and $n=1$, but I haven't found any yet. So perhaps $n\geq 2$ is needed there, or maybe there are none...
